# Rails specify routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have both my login and signup forms on the same page. I'm trying to specify which 'post' route should be taken based on which form is being filled out. The post of the signup form should be sent to the create_user action and the post of the login form should be sent to the create action. Form some reason regardless of what I specify in the view, the create_user action - even for the login form.

Routes:

```
  get '/login' => 'sessions#new', as: :users
  post '/login' => 'sessions#create_user'  
  post '/login' => 'sessions#create'
```

View:

```
    <div class="forms">

    <div class="login">

        <h3>Login</h3>

        <%= form_for(:session, url: {action: "create"}) do |x| %>
            <%= x.email_field :email, :placeholder => " Email", :style => "height:50px; width:350px; border: solid #ff4d4d; background-color:#eff5f5; margin-top:20px; padding-left:5px;" %>
            <%= x.password_field :password, :placeholder => " Password", :style => "height:50px; width:350px; border: solid #ff4d4d; background-color:#eff5f5; margin-top: 35px; padding-left:5px;" %>
            <%= x.submit "Login" %>
        <% end %>

    </div>

    <div class="divide"></div>

    <div class="signup">

        <h3>Signup</h3>

        <%= form_for @new_user, url: {action: "create_user"} do |x| %>
            <%= x.text_field :name, :placeholder => " Name", :style => "height:50px; width:350px; margin-top:20px; border: solid #ff4d4d; background-color:#eff5f5; padding-left:5px;" %>
            <%= x.email_field :email, :placeholder => " Email", :style => "height:50px; width:350px; margin-top:35px; border: solid #ff4d4d; background-color:#eff5f5; padding-left:5px;" %>
            <%= x.password_field :password, :placeholder => " Password", :style => "height:50px; width:350px; margin-top:35px; border: solid #ff4d4d; background-color:#eff5f5; padding-left:5px;" %>
            <%= x.submit "Submit" %>
        <% end %>

    </div>

</div>
```

Controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
def new 
    @new_user = User.new
end

def create
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        session[:user_id] = @user.id 
        redirect_to '/'
    else
        render '/login'
    end
end

def create_user
    @new_user = User.new(user_params)
    if @new_user.save
        session[:user_id] = @new_user.id 
        redirect_to '/'
    else
        render '/login'
    end     
end

def destroy 
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to '/login'
end

private
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it weird, but this should work. . .

Change this:

```
<%= form_for @new_user, url: {action: "create_user"} do |x| %>
```

To this:

```
<%= form_for @new_user, url: url_for(controller: 'sessions_controller', action: 'create_user') do |x| %>
```

---

You should probably consider moving the `create user` stuff into another controller (a UsersController).  If you configure your routes properly (add `resources :users`) you'd only need to use `form_for @new_user` without telling it which controller/action to post to.

Comment: After adding the user resources and moving the new and create_user actions into the users controller I am now getting an argument error and I think it's because I'm using the '@new_user' variable in session's new view while the variable is only present in the users new and create actions. How do I fix this? @Ecnalyr

Comment: @nums Since that's a different problem, proper etiquette on stack exchange suggests you vote this correct response up, mark it as correct then make a new question for it :) .

Comment: Ok is there anyway I can link you to the new question to help answer it? @ Ecnalyr

Comment: @nums I'll be able to see it from your profile page.

Comment: Ok the post will be up in around a half hour due to the 90 minute waiting time. @Ecnalyr

Comment: @nums Looks like someone else answered your question!  That's why we create new questions for new problems.  The answer for that question would not have been possible with the data in this question because you introduced the error in code that wasn't visible here.  Congratulations on having your problem solved!